# DOM ready event inside Electron how?

Tags: electron

This is a silly question, but I could not find a clear answer on the web.

Do I need to listen to a special "dom-ready-event" if my app is running within a `BrowserWindow` in Electron?  For instance in a Cordova/PhoneGap app I read you can start doing things after the `deviceready` event.

I would like to know how this is done in Electron? Is one of the following enough?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", startApp);
window.addEventListener("load", startApp);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordova has `deviceready` because it has both native code and JavaScript code, and potentially JavaScript might run before the native code has finished loading.

You don't have the same problem in Electron. You have a main process (`main.js`) which creates your `BrowserWindow`, so by the time any client-side JavaScript is running, your main process has definitely already started because it was the thing that created your browser window in the first place!

Inside the browser window the same events fire as they would on a normal webpage. So if you *wanted* to, you could use `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` (for the difference see [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)), just in the same way as you would for a regular web application. But you certainly don't need to before calling any of the Electron APIs.